# Ant design active side bar menu color issue

Tags: reactjs, layout, antd

In the image and code provided, a sidebar menu has been created using Ant Design and ReactJS. However, there is a simple issue. A dropdown menu for "Courses" has a sub-item "All Courses," and when "All Courses" is clicked, the parent menu ("Courses") color turns green by default. The Ant Design theme editor has been followed, but no solution has been found.

The desired behavior is that when a dropdown menu item is clicked, the parent menu item's color (in this case, "Courses") should be white. Currently, the parent menu color is turning green, which leads to visibility issues due to the same color as the sidebar background.

To address this, the goal is to configure it so that when a dropdown menu is clicked, the parent menu's color is set to white or another specified color. However, the method to achieve this configuration is currently unknown.

images:
[image]
[image]
my code is:

sidebar items:

```
  const adminSidebarItems: MenuProps["items"] = [
{
  key: `/${role}/dashboard`,
  label: "Dashboard",
  icon: <MdOutlineDashboard />,
},
{
  key: `/${role}/students`,
  label: "Students",
  icon: <GoPeople />,
},

{
  key: `/${role}/courses`,
  label: "Courses",
  icon: <BsBook />,
  children: [
    {
      key: `/${role}/courses/`,
      label: "All Courses",
    },
  ],
},
{
  key: `/${role}/mentors`,
  label: "Mentors",
  icon: <IoPersonCircleOutline />,
},

{
  key: `/${role}/departments`,
  label: "Departments",
  icon: <LuFolders />,
},
{
  key: `/${role}/attendence`,
  label: "Attendence",
  icon: <PiIdentificationCard />,
},
{
  key: `/${role}/events`,
  label: "Events",
  icon: <BsCalendar2Event />,
},
...defaultSidebarItems.slice(0, 1),
{
  key: `/${role}/wallet`,
  label: "Wallet",
  icon: <HiOutlineCreditCard />,
},
{
  key: "/setting",
  label: "setting",
  icon: <IoSettingsOutline />,
},
...defaultSidebarItems.slice(2),];
```

my dashboard layout code :

```
const DashboardLayout = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const { role } = getuser(userKey);

  const selectedKey =
    // @ts-ignore
    sidebarItems(role)?.find((item) => pathname.startsWith(item.key))?.key ||
    `/${role}/dashboard`;

  console.log(selectedKey);

  console.log(pathname);

  const {
    token: { colorBgContainer },
  } = theme.useToken();
  const handleMenuSelect = ({ key }: { key: string }) => {
    // setSelectedKey(key);
    if (key === "/logout") {
      removeUserInfo(userKey);
      navigate("/signin");
    } else {
      navigate(key);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ConfigProvider theme={sidebardThemes}>
      <Layout>
        <Sider
          width="220px"
          trigger={null}
          collapsible
          collapsed={collapsed}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#2492EB",
            height: "100vh",

            zIndex: 2,
            overflow: "auto",
            position: "fixed",
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              height: "inherit",
            }}
          >
            <div className="demo-logo-vertical" />
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "white",
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                height: "100px",
              }}
            >
              <img
                style={{
                  height: "40px",
                  width: "180px",
                }}
                src={logo}
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
            <Menu
              mode="inline"
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "#2492EB",
                color: "white",
                marginTop: "10px",
                flexGrow: 1,
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                paddingBlockEnd: "1rem",
                // height: "100%",
              }}
              selectedKeys={[pathname]}
              // defaultSelectedKeys={[sidebarItems[0].key]}
              // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
              // @ts-ignore
              items={sidebarItems(role)}
              onClick={handleMenuSelect}
            ></Menu>
          </div>
        </Sider>

        <Layout>
          <Content
            style={{
              paddingTop: "130px",

              paddingLeft: collapsed ? "130px" : "270px",
              paddingRight: "50px",
              background: "#F6F8FA",

              overflow: "auto",
            }}
          >
            <Outlet />
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum codesandbox example? so I can do some tests to help you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ant Design version 5, you can change the background color with ConfigProvider like in this documentation:

https://ant.design/components/menu#design-token

```
<ConfigProvider
          key={"config-provider"}
          theme={{
            components: {
              Menu: {
                groupTitleColor: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
                iconSize: 10,
                itemColor: "rgba(136, 140, 159, 1)",
                itemSelectedColor: "#3699FF",
                itemSelectedBg: "#1A1A27",
                itemActiveBg: "#1A1A27",

                itemHoverColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
                itemHoverBg: "rgba(26, 26, 39, 1)",

                subMenuItemBg: "rgba(30, 30, 45, 1)",
                subMenuItemBorderRadius: 0,

                itemBorderRadius: 0,
                itemMarginBlock: 0,
                itemMarginInline: 0,

                popupBg: "#1E1E2D",
                colorBgElevated: "#1E1E2D",
              },
            },
          }}
        >
// YOUR COMPONENTS HERE //
        </ConfigProvider>
```